# Bash script launches the first switch-case loop option again

Tags: bash

Here's the code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function print_help() {
    echo "Just a pile of echos; no other logic here"
}

die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

IpAddress=
SourceDir=
DestDir=
backup=0
restore=0

while :; do
    case $1 in
        ''|-h|\?|--help) print_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        -b|--backup)
            if [ $restore -eq 0 ]; then
                backup=1
                echo "Taking backup..."
            else
                die "ERROR: Can't perform backup and restore at the same time."
            fi
            ;;
        -r|--restore)
            if [ $backup -eq 0 ]; then
                restore=1
                echo "Restoring backup..."
            else
                die "ERROR: Can't perform backup and restore at the same time."
            fi
            ;;
        --ip)
            if [ "$2" ]; then
                ip=$2
                shift
            else
                die 'ERROR: "--ip" requires a non-empty option argument.'
            fi
            ;;
        --ip=?*)
            IpAddress=${1#*=}
            echo "IP Address: $IpAddress"
            ;;
        --source-dir=?*)
            SourceDir=${1#*=}
            if [ -d "$SourceDir" ]; then
                echo "Source Directory: $SourceDir indeed exists"
            else
                die "ERROR: $SourceDir doesn't exist."
            fi
            ;;
        --source-dir=)
            die 'ERROR: "--source-dir" requires a non-empty argument.'
            ;;
        --dest-dir=?*)
            DestDir=${1#*=}
            if [ -w "$DestDir" ]; then
                echo "Destination Directory: $DestDir indeed exists and is writable."
            else
                die "ERROR: $DestDir doesn't exist or is not writable for current user."
            fi
            ;;
        --dest-dir=)
            die 'ERROR: "--dest-dir" requires a non-empty argument.'
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        -?*)
            printf 'Warning: Unknown option (ignoring): %s\n' "$1" >&2
            ;;
        *)
            break
    esac

    shift
done
```

So far, I've tested two use cases, with directories:

1. `/tmp/back/` (in which user has no read permissions) and
2. `/tmp/back2/` (which fully belongs to the user).

The 1st option launched correctly prints the error message:

```
$ ./backup.sh -b --source-dir=/opt/ --dest-dir=/tmp/back/
Taking backup...
Source Directory: /opt/ indeed exists
ERROR: /tmp/back/ doesn't exist or is not writable for current user.
```

Meanwhile the 2nd option confirms that data is OK, and seems to come back to the `print_help` case:

```
$ ./backup.sh -b --source-dir=/opt/ --dest-dir=/tmp/back2/
Taking backup...
Source Directory: /opt/ indeed exists
Destination Directory: /tmp/back2/ indeed exists and is writable.
backup.sh: backup.sh <-b|r> [-h] [server IP] <source dir> <dest dir>
  Take or restore a backup of files.
```

What should be corrected here in order to exit the script after all options are checked one time?

Comment: In the second set of output ... where do the lines: `backup.sh: backup.sh <-b|r> ... Take or restore a backup of files.` come from? I don't see anything in the code provided that matches any of this ...?? or is this output from a script that is different from what's been posted here?

Comment: Oh, it's an actual output of the `print_help` function. The function itself was trimmed, as I found it not relevant for the question.

Comment: I cut-n-pasted your entire script into my env, ran the script (with local directories) and mimicing your 2nd example run I get the `print_help()` output and the script exits with `0`; I even changed the `exit 0` to `exit 23`, re-ran the 2nd test, got the same `print_help()` output and was kicked out to the terminal/command prompt where `echo $?` ==> `23`; at this point it appears (to me) that we don't have an exact copy of your script (ie, unable to duplicate the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all args ended `$1` is `''` that is why it comes back to the `print_help`

> What should be corrected here in order to exit the script after all
> options are checked one time?

Change `print_help` pattern to `*)` and `'')` should be `exit 0`

But better change while condition to:

```
while [[ $1 ]]; do
    ...
done
```

And this check could be added at the beginning of the script:

```
[[ $1 ]] || print_help
```

to print help message and exit if no args passed to the script.

Comment: Is there an option to print the help message when no parameters were given?

Comment: Check it at the beginig before `while` loop `[[ $1 ]] || print_help`

Comment: Please add it to your answer and I'm accepting it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `while` loop is an infinite loop, and you only break out of that loop in two of your 12 cases, or when an error occurs. So unless the code encounters those two cases, or an error, it will keep iterating even when there are no more parameters to read. When all of the parameters have been `shift`ed, `$1` will evaluate to an empty string, which is explicitly listed in your first case (`''|-h|\?|--help) print_help`), resulting in the help message.

The solution is to test for the existence of parameters in your while loop:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    print_help
    exit 1
fi

while [ $1 -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|\?|--help) print_help
    ...
done
```

That way, when the last parameter has been `shift`ed, the loop will end.

Comment: But that wouldn't print the help message if no parameters were supplied.

Comment: You are correct. However, the test for '' does isn't exactly a test for no parameters. It just so happens that a missing parameter expands to the empty string. But you could still pass in an empty string as a parameter and have it match. I have updated the example to add an explicit test for 0 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `''` from the case statement and test if there are no arguments before the loop:

```
[[ $1 ]] || { print_help ; exit 0 ; }

while :; do
    case $1 in
        -h|\?|--help) print_help
            exit 0
        ;;
```